# Three js rotate mesh towards a sphere

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation, jquery-animate

I'm kinda new in Three js and I've been struggling with this for a while.

I have a 3d model facing a certain direction.
There is also a sphere around it and before moving the mesh, I want to animate it's rotation so it will face specified sphere.

So far I managed to get the angle of rotation but I suppose that is not the way to go

this is what I use for rotating the object towards a specified point:

```
if(movementTarget) { playerModel.lookAt(movementTarget); }
```

and this is the content of the

```
movementTarget = {x:154,y:55,z:35};
```

seems like the model is not actually orienting towards the sphere, but an empty spot, not sure what is the issue

Comment: how about `model.lookAt( sphere.position )` ?

Comment: That's what I already tried, but seems like the model is not actually orienting towards the sphere, but an empty spot, not sure what is the issue but I  guess I need to adjust object Z axis to point the sphere, the sphere is generated by another script, so basically what I do is that I render some variable values as an object in 3d space

Comment: hum, that could be caused by children rotation, maybe some children are rotated while the parent is not ?

Comment: this is what I use for rotating the object towards a specified point
if(movementTarget)
{
    playerModel.lookAt(movementTarget);
}

and this is the content of the movementTarget = {x:154,y:55,z:35};

Comment: this is fine. but are you sure all `playerModel`'s children have a correct - null - initial rotation ? try with a simple box instead maybe ?

Comment: Yes, the default rotation is not set, just the camera position `camera.position.set(0,0,-250); // Setting the camera look behind the ship`, if I try to rotate the model towards a static sphere, it works as expected

Comment: I have found the issue.. the orientation was perfectly fine, the issue was that I have multiplied each rendered object coordinates by 10 in order to give impression of a larger distance  between the objects, and seems that I forgot to multiply the coordinates by 10 when looking at the sphere

Comment: I added the content from your comment to the question, maybe you can check it out and add more of your code and your issue so that it is more clear what you tried and why it isn't working... If you solved the question, please answer it yourself and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the issue, the coordinate system had a general variable which amplified the distance between the objects, by calling `lookAt()` function, the camera was oriented in the correct direction, but since the corrdinates Were not multiplied since they came straight from the server.